# Flickering screen Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia, screen

I got a HP Spectre with a 4K screen ([specs](https://support.hp.com/nl-nl/document/c05795765)) and I am currently running Ubuntu 20.04. During boot the GRUB menu is sometimes flickering. This can be so bad that it becomes impossible to read the different boot options. In most cases the flickering disappears again once Ubuntu has booted. However, sometimes the screen starts flickering again. This mostly happens when the laptop has been on for a couple of hours. Under Software and updates -> Additional drivers I have nvidia-driver-440 selected. Sporadically I boot into Windows and I have not seen the screen flickering there.

I hope someone is able to help me solve this issue. The flickering screen during boot is annoying but I can work with it. But the flickering screen while Ubuntu is running can be very annoying. If more information is needed please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was simply to select Ubuntu Wayland on the login screen instead of the legacy Ubuntu GUI which runs on X server (click on the sprocket first).

Answer (score 0):

I installed Xubuntu 20.04 LTS on two seemingly identical Compaq CQ60 laptops, and it worked flawlessly on one of them.  The second laptop had a flickering screen problem right away.  I tried reinstalling, changing the resolution and refresh rate, using the Nvidia third party driver (even worse), installing gnome desktop, changing to Wayland vs Xorg, and nothing worked.  Once my screen started flickering, I usually had to reboot.

The last thing I tried appears to have fixed the problem… Assuming these AMD Sempron laptops with 3GB of memory are very low on resources, I turned off the compositor by navigating to Settings Manager, Windows Manager Tweaks and unchecking Enable Display Compositing.  So far, a week later, I have had no further problems.

Answer (score -1):

This sounds similar to my issue. If your ubuntu screen is flashing colours then it is similar to my issue. At first I thought it was just 20.04 but then when I install 18.04 back, the same thing occured. So I thought my PC had a faulty graphics card. but nope card is good.

After further research it seems there is more likely a driver compatibility issue. Since I never had any issue with 18.04 (for 2 years) I think maybe the libraries that is part of the update has a faulty Intel driver.

This is how I fix my issue.
Get into ubuntu via the "recovery mode". I'm not sure which key I press during boot to open this option. On dual boot there is an advance option to allow you to boot to recovery mode.

On the terminal type
"sudo gedit /etc/default/grub"

Find this line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash". And change it to "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset".
"nomodeset" somehow disables the graphic card and it makes the resolution of my screen small.
Find this line "#GRUB_GFXMODE=". remove the # and change the resolution

Once complete type "sudo update-grub"

Doing this has stop the flickering. Only problem is that no sound will come out of the HDMI cable. But the speaker port of my PC still works

Comment: Hi Karen, thanks for your help. I tried your approach but get stuck in the "Recovery menu". When I choose root here and execute "sudo gedit /etc/default/grub" I get: "Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused". Any clue what I am doing wrong?