# Screen flickers in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, flicker

My screen flickers when I open the lid after having closed the lid earlier, it keeps on flickering and doesn't stop. It flickers even when I go to shell (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>), but if I lock it again (<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) and then unlock it, everything gets back to normal, rebooting works too.

I'm not able to understand the problem, or even where to begin with. I've looked at few similar questions on askubuntu to no avail, since the problem seems a bit different.

Another thing: I faced this problem months back in Ubuntu 21.10, but then I downgraded to ubuntu 20.04 and didn't get this problem until few days ago.

output of $ sudo lshw -c video

```
*-display                 
       description: Display controller
       product: Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: c1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:91 memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e01fffff memory:fe500000-fe57ffff memory:fe580000-fe59ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Renoir
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       version: c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi msix vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0
       resources: irq:52 memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c01fffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe400000-fe47ffff
```

I've shifted to kernel 5.11 and restored a snapshot to when I wasn't facing the problem, so far the problem hasn't surfaced again, I'll update if I face the problem again

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your hardware. Can you provide some system details.

Comment: @elmclose I've added some more info, also I was using kernel 5.13. Let me know if I need to add more details, specific commands would help.

Comment: If the flickering comes back try turning off the compositor. See this post for more detail https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241696